# Java web. Path to file, context.getResponse

Tags: java, stripes

This code makes the download of ".pdf" file:

```
context.getResponse().addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+level2 + ".pdf");
```

So I can only set the name of file (in my case it is level2). But I need to set full path to file. How can I do that? 
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean set the full path? The full path the file will be written to? That is not possible. The path the file will be downloaded from, i.e. the path in the server? This is not configured this way.

Comment: Yes, the path in the server

Comment: How does this relate to JWS?